# C program that reads a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that reads (accepts) a sentence with spaces until the user ends it with a point.
for some reason, my code stops when the user types two points instead of only one, I'll leave my code below:

```
char sent[100];
int i;    

printf("Write a sentence and end it with a point :\n");

for (i=0; sent[i]!='.'; i++)
{
    scanf("%s",&sent[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think this loop does? `for (i=0;  sent[i]!='.'; i++)`

Comment: You're testing `sent[i]` *before* you fill it in.

Comment: `%s` reads a whole word, not a single character.

Comment: Your use of `&sent[i]` makes very little sense. If the user types `abc defg.` it's going to write `abc` into `char[0]` through `char[2]`, then it will write `defg` into `char[1]` through `char[4]`, overwriting part of `abc`.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: @Barmar: It's like he meant `%c` but I object to `scanf`.

Comment: @Barmar I want it to read a whole word, the main project is to read a sentence that ends with a point and assign each repeated word to a number, so wouldn't I need to use %s?

Comment: But why are you reading each word into overlapping parts of the string?

Comment: If they type `abc defg.` then `sent` will contain `adefg.`

Comment: Read the whole line into a string with `fgets()`, then search for the `.` with `strchr()`.

Answer (score 2):

This code will match the first 99 non-period characters and save them in `sent`.

```
char sent[100];

scanf("%99[^.]", sent);
```